# $dbh is not a recognized variable when it is set?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting the following message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in /var/www/PDO/Functions/PDOFunctions.php on line 12 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/PDO/Functions/PDOFunctions.php on line 12

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo', 'root', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
global  $dbh;


function PDOFetch($Var)
{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("$Var"); //Error Line
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $result; 
}

function PDONumb ($Var)
{
    $Query = $dbh->prepare("{$Var}");
    $Execute->execute();
    $count = $Execute->rowCount();
    return $count;
}
```

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: `global $dbh` goes inside the functions.

Comment: Take a look at my simple [DByte library](https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte).

Comment: The problem is you don't know how `global` works. You should have googled this and read the documentation before asking a question on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, to access a global variable in a function, you have to declare that it belongs to global scope by using the global keyword.

```
function PDOFetch($Var)
{
    global $dbh;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("$Var"); //Error Line
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $result; 
}
```

All variables used in a function are local to that function unless declared to be imported from the global scope.

The NOTICE error is a helpful warning that you may be doing something you didn't expect.

Comment: Fixed the problem, will mark as answer in 10 minutes when the timer lets me :) thankyou

Answer (score 3):

Using global variables is bad practice.  For something as easy as this, you could rewrite your code as a simple class.  In doing so, you also get the added benefit of easily being able to create and use multiple database handles.

```
class Db 
{
    private $dbh = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo', 'root', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
    }

    public function PDOFetch($Var)
    {
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("$Var"); //Error Line
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $result; 
    }

    public function PDONumb ($Var)
    {
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("{$Var}");
        $sth->execute();
        $count = $sth->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }
    // Other methods here
}
```

Then it's:

```
$dbc1 = new Db();
$dbc2 = new Db();  // Hey I have 2 connections now, cool
$result1 = $dbc1->PDOFetch(..);
$result2 = $dbc2->PDOFetch(..);
```

Note, that your PDONumb was broken and wouldn't work, so I threw in a fix for that as well.

Comment: Will look into implimenting this into my system! thankyou! and yeah, I was literly just reviewing that one :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare a variable global once and then it's available in all functions.

You declare the global variable in each function that needs to have access to it.

See the examples of using `global` in http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php